# Does SimpleDateFormat utilize Unicode Technical Standard #35?

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat

I noticed when working on iOS that the `dateFormat` string passed to `NSDateFormatter` looked very similar to the format string utilized when initializing a `new SimpleDateFormat()` object. For instance:

- `yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss zzz`
- `yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ`
- etc

Since they looked ***similar***, I began to wonder if they were actually identical. So I set out to try and figure out exactly what standard was being utilized.

I found that [iOS NSDateFormatter utilizes Unicode Technical Standard #35](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW13)

I couldn't find any similar documentation for what standard is being utilized by `SimpleDateFormat` in Android. Is this a custom format that ***happens*** to look a lot like UTS-35, or is it ***indeed*** UTS-35? What official source would have this answer?

Comment: `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` has been part of Java since the beginning. Java 1 was released January 1996, and UTS-35 didn't exist until 2004, so if anything, it's the other way around: UTS-35 happens to look a lot like SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: Do you have any idea what standard (if any) was used for the date format string of `SimpleDateFormat`? Did the crew over at Java literally invent their own standard for it instead of using the (already 10 year old) POSIX standard?